# Splitting by regex or ebnf

Tags: java, regex, ebnf

I've got a string like:

```
create Person +fname : String, +lname: String, -age:int;
```

Is there any possibility to split it by regex or ebnf? I mean all the things like `[a-zA-Z0-9]` (things we don't know) will be stored in array?

In other words, by using this regexp:

```
^create [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]* [s|b]?[+|[-]|=][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*[ ]?:[ ]?[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*(, [s|b]?[+|[-]|=][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*[ ]?:[ ]?[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)*;
```

I want to obtain array:

- Person
- +
- fname
- String
- +
- lname
- String
- -
- age
- int

Comment: can you give an example input line?

Comment: example input line is that string. `create Person +fname : String, +lname: String, -age:int;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to split it this way

```
String[] tokens = "create Person +fname : String, +lname: String, -age:int;"
        .split("[\\s:;,]+|(?<=[+\\-])");
        //split on set of characters containing spaces:;, OR after + or -. 
for (String s : tokens)
    System.out.println("=> " + s);
```

output:

```
=> create
=> Person
=> +
=> fname
=> String
=> +
=> lname
=> String
=> -
=> age
=> int
```

As you can see it will put `create` at start of your array so just start iterating from `tokens[1]`.

You could try do add `^create\\s` as part of splitting rule, but this will produce empty string at start of tokens array, so won't solve anything.

Comment: I'm wondering if there is any function which allows me "catch" results by regexp or ebnf, ignoring constant characters like i.e. `create`.

Comment: @Hladeo I am not sure what you are trying to do. If there is pattern like `a bb x dd` and you only want to find what is under lets say `a` and `c` you can use groups -> for regex "(\\w+) bb (\\w+) dd" what was under `a` will be stored in group(1) and `c` group(2).

Comment: @Hladeo you can also remove first words that you want to ignore before splitting like `inputString.replaceAll("\\b(word1|word2|word3)\\b","").split("regexForSplit")`

Answer (score 0):

Regex is fine for lots of things, but sometimes you need a real lexer. [JFlex](http://jflex.de/) is great. There's no tokenization task it can't handle. If you need to go a little further and create a parse tree, [JavaCC](https://javacc.java.net/) or [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) are good choices.